# Discovered an inground hot tub in the back yard of my duplex, looking for ideas

Tags: backyard, hot-tub, advice

Important note! I am renting this property. Just looking for ways to improve my backyard so I enjoy spending time out there.

I have had a bunch of snake plants growing in the backyard. They were oddly placed and kind of unsightly and always had wasps buzzing around them, so I tore them out. I had thought that they were in some kind of planter because there was a cement ring around them, but it turned out to be an in-ground, approximately 6' x 8' x 3' hot tub.

I'm not sure if the owner is aware of this, as he just purchased this property recently, so I will let him know. But the hot tub is completely filled with dirt and I'm looking for ideas for something to do with the space that I can present to the owner. I think taking it out will be too cost prohibitive. Should I leave it filled? Investigate it more? Thoughts for what to do if I scoop out the dirt?

Comment: Generally, if hot tubs are filled with dirt, that means they reached a condition where it was no longer worth repairing them and turning them into a planter made much more sense.

Comment: That's understandable. I am thinking of transforming the space into a firepit or something similar, perhaps I will continue down that route. Thanks for your response!